# image view by using image button

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android. I want to capture a picture through phone camera and also trying to take a picture from phone gallery. At this situation I am successed in one step that is to take picture from the gallery, but at the time of taking picture through camera, i faced a problem that is override method `protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,Intent data)` does not work , error shows and it also hampered the previous override method of the taking picture from gallery. I want to do the two works at a time. so what I have to do now

I have already created
 private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 150;
    Uri imageUrl;

```
private void openGallery() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestcode,resultcode,data);
    if(resultcode == RESULT_OK && requestcode == PICK_IMAGE){
        imageUrl = data.getData();
        im.setImageURI(imageUrl);
    }
}
```

so when I want add another protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) method, it shows error and told that it has already created

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be best if you show us the actual code in addition to describing it in English. Be sure to read [mcve] for some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two methods with the exact same name and parameter list. Instead, you should add code to the existing `onActivityResult()` method to implement the logic for retrieving the pic from the camera.Just add an `else if` clause to the existing `if` statement:

```
if (resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestcode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        // get image from gallery
    } else if (requestcode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        // get image from camera
    }
}
```

Comment: @JannatullHaque If my answer solves your problem, be sure to accept it by clicking the check mark on the left.

Answer (score -1):

**you can use this for taking picture from camera**

*on click of button or any image*

```
 photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST); 
        }
    });
```

**This method will call when you click **

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);//set image to Imageview
    }  
}
```

Comment: `Bundle` does not have a `get()` method, so this answer will not compile. Instead, I think you need to do `data.getStringExtra("data");` which is a URI to the graphics file.